# ResourcesNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a value in my dimens.xml defined as follows:

```
<dimen name="input_text_width">250dp</dimen>
```

I want to use it to dynamically size the width of a TextView, as follows:

```
tv.setWidth(activity.getResources().getInteger(R.dimen.input_text_width));
```

The resource exists (checked in R.java). I have run "clean" on my project more than once. Why do I keep getting this exception?

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050012 type #0x5 is not valid
```

Comment: u might be using a tablet for testing and in values-sw600 or values-sw720 folders in dimens file u may not set this value. check it once

Comment: Did you try with that? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension(int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the dimension pixels...

```
int size = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.input_text_width);
textView.setWidth(size);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have taken this from [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="textview_height">25dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="textview_width">150dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="ball_radius">30dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And in code

```
//Retreive dimension
Resources res = getResources();
float fontSize = res.getDimension(R.dimen.font_size);
```

In your xml

```
<TextView
android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_width"
android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because you use :

```
activity.getResources().getInteger(R.dimen.input_text_width)
```

Instead of :

```
activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.input_text_width);
```